# seleccionar un elemento en un select y traer el id para realizar busqueda en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<div id="leftcolumn">
  <form class="form-register" action="actualizar_insumo.php" method="post">
    <h3>MODIFICAR INSUMOS MEDICOS</h3>
    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
      <input type="hidden" name="cod_item" value="1">
      <div class="contenedor-labels-100">NOMBRE DEL INSUMO</div>
      <div class="select1">
          <select name="insumos" id="item" required>
            <option value="">Seleccione</option>
            <?php
               $datos = "SELECT id,cod_item,nombre,presentacion FROM insumos WHERE cod_item LIKE 'im%'";
                   $ins_med = mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);

                   while ($ins_medicos = mysqli_fetch_array($ins_med)) {

                echo "<option value='".$ins_medicos[id]."''>".$ins_medicos['nombre']." / ".$ins_medicos['presentacion']."</option>";
              }
                  ?>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor-labels-100">PRESENTACION</div>
      <input type="text" class="input-100" name="presentacion" id="presentacion">
      <div class="contenedor-labels-45">FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO</div>
      <div class="contenedor-labels-45">CANTIDAD</div>
      <input type="date" class="input-45" name="fecha_venc" id="fecha_venc">
      <input type="text" class="input-10" name="stock" id="stock">
      <div class="contenedor-labels-100"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn-circular"><img src="imagenes/enviar2.png"></button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Saludos Paul, por favor puedes plantear mejor la pregunta, que es lo que quieres realizar y de que manera, y que resultado estas obteniendo hasta ahora. Así como también mejorar el pegado del código aquí. De esa forma seria mas fácil responderte.

Comment: si vi que el codigo no pego bien, tengo un select que muestra el nombre de productos de una base de datos, osea es dinamico ya que trae estos nombres de una consulta mysql, ahora necesito es tomar el id de ese producto que seleccione en el select y hacer otra consulta en mysql para  llenar unos input con mas informacion referente al producto seleccionado.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, y coloca la estructura de tu código para poder ayudarte por favor.

Comment: Edito la pregunta y se lee el codigo completo, soy nuevo aca, no entiendo porq lo corta al publicar la pregunta

Comment: Bueno con lo que se ve se entiende que lo que tienes hecho es la consulta que te muestra los datos dentro del select. No es asi?

Comment: exacto eso lo realiza muy bien, pero luego de seleccionar un elemento del select necesito su id para buscar otros datos de esa seleccion y colocarlo en unos input la estructura de la tabla es id,nombre,presentacion,fecha_vencimiento,stock necesito mostrar todos esos datos a traves de los input

Comment: para que el usuario pueda modificar por ejemplo stock y envie el nuevo valor para actualizar la data

Comment: function id_insumo(id) {
      id = document.getElementById("insumos").value;
     return id;
      alert(id);
  }

Comment: con este script capturo el id pero no logro traerlo para utilizarlo en otros procesos

Comment: Ok, escribiendo respuesta!

Comment: Revisa la respuesta, prueba y cualquier cosa avisa!

Answer (score 2):

Por lo dicho en tus comentarios estas tratando de realizarlo con un función js. Una pena que no hayas podido ser mas explicito al momento de formular la pregunta y haber mostrado mejor la estructura del código, pero ya esta.

Partiendo de lo que tienes hecho y necesitas hacer, el valor del id de cada producto debes tenerlo en el `value=""` de cada `<option></option>` de tu select, quedando algo asi:

```
<select name="mi-select" id="mi-select">
 <option value="<?php echo $ins_medicos['id'] ?>"></option>
</select>
```

Esto no cambia mucho con lo que tienes, solo que debes colocarle un `id` al select para que lo uses de identificador y mediante ajax gestiones el valor que traiga y así poder realizar la otra consulta que necesitas.

Ahora tendrías que realizar una función que al seleccionar algún producto del select te rellene unos campos de texto que contendrán, supongo, la información de ese producto.

De esta forma puedes hacerlo:

SCRIPT PHP

Aquí puedes manejarlo con un objeto de json que contenga todos los resultados según ese id

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

 $id = $_POST['mi-select'];

 //NO SE COMO TENGAS TU CONEXIÓN A LA BD, NI QUE TIPO DE CONEXIÓN UTILICES, PERO AQUÍ IRÍA

 $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = "$id" LIMIT 1");
  if($sql->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()){
     $filas[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('response'=> true, 'datos'=> $filas)); //MANDAMOS EL ARREGLO CON LOS DATOS EN UN OBJETO DE JSON
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('response'=> false)); //AQUÍ PUEDES MOSTRAR UN AVISO DE QUE NO SE ENCONTRÓ NADA
  }
 } else {
   header('location:index.php');
 }
```

FUNCIÓN AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mi-select').on('change',function(){
    var id = $("#mi-select").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'ver_info.php', //NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO A DONDE IRA LA PETICIÓN AJAX
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'id':id}
    })
    .done(function(result){
      //PREGUNTAS SI CONSIGUIO DATOS EL PHP
      if(result.response == true){
        //EN ESTA PARTE ES DONDE MUESTRAS LOS VALORES EN LOS INPUTS
        $("#input1").val(datos.nombre);
        $("#input2").val(datos.presentacion);
      } else {
        alert("El producto no existe, o X cosa");
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Te explico un poco, el formulario que contiene el select con tu lista de productos lo vas a mandar con ajax a php, php se va a encargar de recuperar el dato que le mando ajax que sera la variable POST que contiene el id del producto, haces la consulta y si encuentra resultados guardas todo en un array el cual ira a un objeto de json, ya teniendo esto puedes mostrarlos dinamicamente en los inputs.

Cabe destacar que esa consulta es vulnerable a inyección SQL, pero como no se la manera en la que estas trabajando te la he puesto de esa forma.

Por ultimo, si vas a hacer el script de ajax en un archivo externo, recuerda que debes invocarlo en el archivo en donde esta tu formulario después de la invocación a la librería de Jquery, de esta manera:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="funciones.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tratare de implementar tu respuesta, no logro entenderla del todo!!!  agradezco mucho tu tiempo y tus conocimientos, te escribo luego de intentarlo.

Comment: Prueba a ver que tal, cualquier cosa me avisas por aca!

Comment: Hola Alejo, resolví con esta función.  Gracias por tu apoyo!!

Comment: Que bueno que sirvió, suerte!

Comment: Recuerda puntuar la respuesta!

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showItem(str){

if (str==""){
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","datos_insumo.php?id_item="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Paul, si esto es una parte de la pregunta, pulsa en editar para añadirla  a la misma, no en la seccion de respuestas. Un saludo